# Thoughts on being load bearing?

Tags: load-bearing

I was almost certain that this wall wasn't load bearing. Both the floor joists above, and joists below in the basement run parallel with the wall.  There isn't another wall directly above, and no posts, or jacks below.  The thing that had me slightly second guessing is after I opened it up the wall runs directly under a parallel joist above and is over one in the basement.  There is also a double top plate, and a solid header above the wall opening without a door.  There are gaps all around the edges of the header though so maybe they just used it as a drywall nailer.  I know it can't be determined from pictures alone, but wondering what anyone thought. I can provide more photos if helpful.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: There are more joists, and only this one had a wall under it. So it can't be load-bearing, especially if there is nothing (wall or studs) directly above it.

Comment: Walls do need need something to anchor to, joists happen to be useful to anchor walls.  That header is not made to be load bearing, too much space on top and bottom.  Double top plates have more uses than just load bearing.

Comment: Yes, it looks in this case like the top plates are there just because the wallboard needs something at the top the same width as the studs to screw to.